# Usage of the C# lock keyword

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I post my understanding of C# lock as follows, please help me validate whether or not I get it right.

```
public class TestLock
{
    private object threadLock = new object();
    ...
    public void PrintOne()
    {
        lock (threadLock)
        {
            // SectionOne
        }
    }

    public void PrintTwo()
    {
        lock (threadLock)
        {
            // SectionTwo
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

**Case I>** Thread1 and Thread2 simultaneously try to call PrintOne.
Since PrintOne is guarded by the instance lock, at any time, only
one thread can exclusively enter the SectionOne.

*Is this correct?*

**Case II>** Thread1 and Thread2 simultaneously try to call PrintOne and PrintTwo
respectively (i.e. Thread1 calls PrintOne and Thread2 calls PrintTwo)
Since two print methods are guarded by the same instance lock, at any time,
only one thread can exclusively access either SectionOne or SectionTwo, but NOT both.

*Is this correct?*

Comment: To summarize the answers below: the code is thread-safe per instance only. When instances share resources, @oleski has the right answer (= No)

Comment: And therefore -1 for not including the shared data/resource. Please edit.

Comment: It's a valid point, but the original question does not say whether or not the instances are separate and, so, from the way the code/question is written it was safe to assume he was talking about the calls being made against the same instance. So, I disagree with your downvote, but that's your perogative.

Comment: You don't need to put tags in the title.. that's what tags are for!

Answer (score 10):

1 and 2 are **true only** if all your threads use **the same** instance of the class. If they use **different instances**, then both cases are **false**

Sample

```
public class TestLock
{
    private  object threadLock = new object();

    public void PrintOne()
    {
        lock (threadLock)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("One");
            var f = File.OpenWrite(@"C:\temp\file.txt"); //same static resource
            f.Close();
        }
    }

    public void PrintTwo()
    {
        lock (threadLock)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Two");
            var f = File.OpenWrite(@"C:\temp\file.txt"); //same static resource
            f.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

And testing code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int caseNumber = 100;

    var threads = new Thread[caseNumber];
    for (int i = 0; i < caseNumber; i++)
    {
        var t = new Thread(() =>
                                {
                                    //create new instance
                                    var testLock = new TestLock();
                                    //for this instance we safe
                                    testLock.PrintOne();
                                    testLock.PrintTwo();
                                });
        t.Start();
        //once created more than one thread, we are unsafe
    }
}
```

One of the possible solutions is to add a static keyword to the locking object declaration and methods that use it.

```
private  static object threadLock = new object();
```

**UPDATE**
Good point made by konrad.kruczynski

> ..."thread safety" is also assumed from
>   context. For example, I could take
>   your file opening code and also
>   generate exception with static lock -
>   just taking another application
>   domain. And therefore propose that OP
>   should use system-wide Mutex class or
>   sth like that. Therefore static case
>   is just inferred as the instance one.

Comment: The code is thread-safe _per instance_. The OP mentions "instance lock" once but is vague about what is actually shared.

Comment: @Henk I agree, he mentioned instance lock, will update my answer. tnx.

Comment: lock performance is very directly related to how much contention there is for the lock.  So you really shouldn't use a static lock unless you are modifying static data and if you are using a static lock you shouldn't use it except for protecting static data.

Comment: @Yaur In my sample I modify the file. It is only one file in the system. There cannot be more than one file in a system with the same name, therefore in this case I regard my file as a static resource. And I modify it by opening it for write. Pls test my code and see it yourself.

Comment: @oleksii, there's nothing technically wrong with your example.  It highlights the problem of using an instance lock when sharing a resource *across* instances.  However, if this were a real-world example, you'd want to make the lock *and the two print methods* static.

Comment: @Matt or perhaps add a global mutex. I just didn't want to change the signature of the methods. But I have added your point to the answer.

Comment: @oleksii, understood and agreed.  Just to clarify, I'm simply stating that sometimes examples used to illustrate a point don't reflect good API design.  IMHO, requiring the consumer to create an instance of any object just to call a method is poor design.  Granted, this point has little to do with the OP's understanding of locks, but it's a point that is often overlooked when discussing things academically.

Answer (score 3):

Case I: Check ✓

Case II: Check ✓

Don't forget that locking is only one way of thread synchronization. For other userfull methods, read: [Thread Synchronization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Straight from MSDN sample:

```
public class TestThreading
{
    private System.Object lockThis = new System.Object();

    public void Process()
    {    
        lock (lockThis)
        {
            // Access thread-sensitive resources.
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: @Teoman please try my sample code and you will get an IOException, file is used. I believe that is a valid case. Locking object **must** be static. If two threads use different instances of the class, there will be two locking instances and the code becomes thread unsafe.

Comment: @Teoman no kidding, really. From msdn "Best practice is to define a private object to lock on, or a private static object variable to protect data common to all instances." So if there are more than one instance of the class, one must use static. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: @oleskii: If the synchronized region does not modify static resources, there's no need for a static lock.  You can't have a race condition between two contexts that don't share data.

Comment: @Sean if I don't need that, what is wrong with my contra sample then? I am talking about the situations where different threads use different instances of the class.

Comment: Your example does not contain any static data, much less any static data that's being modified, so there's no possibility of a race condition related to static data.  All you gain by making the synchronization object static is an opportunity for deadlock.  Now if the two objects share (non-static) references to a shared object, there might be problems - but a static lock won't help you in that case.  That's a problem that's better solved by not letting more than one thread tinker with a non-threadsafe object in the first place.

Comment: @Sean pls give it a minute and run my code, point to the existing file to open it for write. Try and see if you get the exception (two or more threads open the same file for write). Then make the locking object static and run it again. Because it is static, there will be only one instance per application and files will be open for write and closed using the same single lock. This is how one can make sure there is only one thread currently accessing the protected section.

Comment: @oleskii:  True, trying to open a file that's already got an exclusive lock will result in an IOExceptioon.  This is not something you can prevent by using lock statements, because the file could just as well be locked by another object, process, program, or even (in a network environment) computer.  It's a problem that needs to be handled with proper exception handling, not thread synchronization.

Comment: @Sean yes, that is a good point I agree. I used a file opening for write purely to demonstrate that the code is not thread safe (apart from per instance based). My sample shows just that multiple instances are not thread safe, unless the locking object is static.

Comment: @Sean BTW my sample contains static shared resource that is modified which is the file

Comment: External resources are not the same thing as static fields, and it is unwise to conflate the two.  It will invite poor decisions such as, for example, using a synchronization method that only works for issues that are constrained to a single process, such as thread locks, to try and handle concurrency issues related to resources that are not constrained to a single process, such as files.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and yes. Cases are correct.

Comment: @oleksii: just as you said, only per instance safe. However OP written about instance lock.

Comment: I guess @Henk makes sense, the question was vague on this particular issue

Comment: @oleksii: yeah, but taking "thread safety" is also assumed from context. For example, I could take your file opening code and also generate exception with static lock - just taking another application domain. And therefore propose that OP should use system-wide Mutex class or sth like that. Therefore static case is just inferred as the instance one. I think not reason for downvoting.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is 100% correct. So if, for instance, you wanted to allow entry into the two methods separately you would want to have two locks.

Comment: +1 for _"to allow entry into the two methods separately you would want to have two locks"_

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're correct in both counts.

Answer (score 0):

here are the basics (more or less)

1) use instance locks for instance data

```
public class InstanceOnlyClass{
    private int callCount;
    private object lockObject = new object();

    public void CallMe()
    {
        lock(lockObject)
        {
            callCount++;
        }
     }
}
```

2) use static locks for static data

```
public class StaticOnlyClass{
    private int createdObjects;
    private static object staticLockObject = new object();

    public StaticOnlyClass()
    {
        lock(staticLockObject)
        {
            createdObjects++;
        }
    }
}
```

3) if you are protecting static and instance data use separate static and instance locks

```
public class StaticAndInstanceClass{
    private int createdObjects;

    private static object staticLockObject = new object();

    private int callCount;

    private object lockObject = new object();

    public StaticAndInstanceClass()
    {
        lock(staticLockObject)
        {
            createdObjects++;
        }
    }

    public void CallMe()
    {
        lock(lockObject)
        {
            callCount++;
        }
     }
}
```

based on this your code is fine if you are accessing instance data but unsafe if you are modifying static data